# deploying React App on Heroku with netlify getting CORS errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, netlify

[Getting this error tried everything I search still don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ6tM.jpg)

[Added express cors still dont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c7wG.jpg)

[Added netlify.toml redirects still no life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOB1U.jpg)

Comment: are your herokuapp deploy success? it url is right??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.